# PHP- How to display a specific form based on a selection?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm new in the word of html and PHP, so I would like to ask a question: in the HTMl code there is a form and inside that there are two options to select: lesson or topic.
I would like to show a form when the user selects "lesson" and another one if the user select "topic".
How can I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create a lesson</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {

        if($_POST["argumetOrLesson"] == "topic")
        {
            //form to input a topic
        }
        else
        {
            //form to input a lesson

        }

    ?>

    <form method="post" action= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
    <label for="argumetOrLesson">Topic or Lesson?</label>
    <select id="argumetOrLesson" name="argumetOrLesson">
      <option value="topic">Topic</option>
      <option value="lesson">Lesson</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the issue? just write in condition whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

We can use multiple php statements to separate the HTML from the PHP, but still use the PHPs conditional statements.

A nice, quick, and simple way I would do it is:

```
<?php if($_POST["argumetOrLesson"] == "topic") { ?>
<form>
    ..your topic form html here...
</form>
<?php } else { ?>
<form>
    ..your topic form html here...
</form>
<? } ?>
```

Obviously, space it out a bit and make the code formatting pretty, but it'll do the trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a syntax error in your code. You forgot the closing of first if statement. Replace your php code with this:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

    if($_POST["argumetOrLesson"] == "topic")
    {
        //form to input a topic
    }
    else
    {
        //form to input a lesson

    }
}
?>
```